# Python pandas print each group from a groupby object as a single row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I am having a groupby object

```
ref query_x query_y
    
ANN00118-RA Charonia_GIQZ01011680.1.p1  Typhlosyrinx_Contig7942.p1
ANN00127-RA Charonia_GIQZ01023156.1.p1  Typhlosyrinx_Contig11188.p1
ANN00130-RA Charonia_GIQZ01000168.1.p1  Typhlosyrinx_Contig15281.p1
```

The data are grouped by the column "ref". It happens that many lines have the same ref, for example

```
test.get_group('ANN12010-RA')


        query_x ref query_y
0   Charonia_GIQZ01000001.1.p1  ANN12010-RA Typhlosyrinx_Contig13935.p1
1   Charonia_GIQZ01000001.1.p1  ANN12010-RA Typhlosyrinx_Contig13936.p1
2   Charonia_GIQZ01000001.1.p1  ANN12010-RA Typhlosyrinx_TRINITY_DN17744_c0_g2_i1.p1
3   Charonia_GIQZ01000001.1.p1  ANN12010-RA Typhlosyrinx_TRINITY_DN18267_c0_g1_i1.p2
```

As you see, the second column has identical values ANN12010-RA, I would like to print each "ref" block in its own file, on a single row. Expected output from the example

```
ANN12010-RA Charonia_GIQZ01000001.1.p1  Typhlosyrinx_Contig13935.p1 Charonia_GIQZ01000001.1.p1 Typhlosyrinx_Contig13936.p1 Charonia_GIQZ01000001.1.p1 Typhlosyrinx_TRINITY_DN17744_c0_g2_i1.p1 Charonia_GIQZ01000001.1.p1 Typhlosyrinx_TRINITY_DN18267_c0_g1_i1.p2
```

The order of elements is not important. The number of columns per row can vary, I don't know how many elements each group has.

What's the best way to achieve this? Knowing the groupby object can be thousands of lines long.

Thanks a lot

Using the answer I am getting this

```
group_df.head()
index   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 845 846 847 848 849 850 851 852 853 854
ref                                                                                 
ANN12010-RA Charonia_GIQZ01000001.1.p1 Typhlosyrinx_Con...  Charonia_GIQZ01000001.1.p1 Typhlosyrinx_Con...  Charonia_GIQZ01000001.1.p1 Typhlosyrinx_TRI...  Charonia_GIQZ01000001.1.p1 Typhlosyrinx_TRI...  Charonia_GIQZ01000001.1.p1 Typhlosyrinx_TRI...
```

The ref element should be an element of the row, or at least I should be able to print it (which I think is possible). The only remaining issue is that, columns are made out of pairs of values and not a single value. As an output, I would like to print a file with one element per line. Ok, I can use awk to convert a 2 columns output to a 1 column output but I thought I would figure in Python.

And I would like that my output file has as name the "ref", so here my output would be idealy a single file with a single column and the file would be named ANN12010-RA.

Does that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard for me to test this on my end, as there is no code to get your data on my end to toy around.

I believe this may work, though:

```py
# Same should work for your 'test' DF as a whole if you remove the .get_group(...) method below.
# Though it is unclear the format of 'test' from your question, so not sure.
group_df = test.get_group('ANN12010-RA').reset_index()

# If either column is not already str, you should convert:
group_df['query_x'] = group_df['query_x'].astype(str)
group_df['query_y'] = group_df['query_y'].astype(str)

# Make a "Joined" column for the queries. You can change '    ' to whatever you'd like.
group_df['joined'] = group_df[['query_x', 'query_y']].agg('    '.join, axis=1)

# Pivot the DF to display all on one line.
group_df = group_df.pivot(index='ref', columns='index', values='joined')
```

Give it a try and let me know how it works for you.

EDIT: regarding the output, I want to group all the elements that match the same 'ref' displayed on the same row. Simply like this (first element is the ref that served to group)

```
ANN12010-RA Charonia_GIQZ01000001.1.p1 Typhlosyrinx_Con...  Charonia_GIQZ01000001.1.p1 Typhlosyrinx_Con...  Charonia_GIQZ01000001.1.p1 Typhlosyrinx_TRI...  Charonia_GIQZ01000001.1.p1 Typhlosyrinx_TRI...  Charonia_GIQZ01000001.1.p1 Typhlosyrinx_TRI...
```

but as a data.frame object I can then easily export to a csv file.

Comment: Hello, that gives the desired output, thanks a lot. Now I have a last request, I actually have a long list of different "ref" in my group_by object.  I suppose I can simply loop through it and have an independent file for each ref? Sorry I am a very beginner with python and pythonic idiom.

Comment: My other problem is that in the group_df the ref element is not an element of the row, it acts as the "row title" but I actually need it to be a row element, or at least a way to print it, as I want in the end to print in a text file the group_df, and it should contain the "ref" element.

Comment: I have edited mu question to add what your code give. I don't know if it's the way to do things on stack.

Comment: Sure! So, once you feel my solution is acceptable, you click the checkmark by my answer. That said, I don't think I've properly answered your question; I didn't know you wanted a different layout/output, but we can definitely do that. Would you please edit your question to add an example head of what you would like to see in the resultant file?